# POST Method is not Sending All Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am working with angular, node, express, and postgresql/sequelize in a fun little project. However, it has gotten a little too fun. I am new to developing in this environment, so I may be using some incorrect structures. But, I am trying to set up an update route for a model. The JS for the update is seemingly good, as it does as it should, but the problem here is that when the function is called and the post method is initiated, it does not grab the values from the form group, in html.

Here is a snippet of the html/angular:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="SomethingCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="updateSomething(updateform)" role="form" ng-init="updateform = {}">
      <div class="datagrid"><table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> ID </th>
          <th> field1 </th>
          <th> field2 </th>
          <th> field3 </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="something in somethings | filter:{id:somethingId} | orderBy:'id' | limitTo: 1 track by $index">
          <td>
            {{something.id}}
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="field1" value="{{something.field1}}"/>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="field2" value="{{something.field2}}">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="number" name="field3" value="{{something.field3}}">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit"><strong>Update</strong></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I go into network analysis of this, it sends JSON data, but it does not specify the value -- but, from the response I get in console log I think it only sends current date as the only attribute that is updated is updateTime.

Here is the JS, which I think works:

```
exports.UpdateSomethings = function (req, res) {
  models.Something.find({
    where: {
      id: req.params.id
    }
  }).then(function (something) {
    if (something) { // if the record exists in the db    
      something.updateAttributes({
        field1: req.body.field1,
        field2: req.body.field2,
        field3: req.body.field3
      }).then(function (somethings) {
        res.json(somethings.dataValues);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("ops: " + error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'error' });
      });
    }
    ;
  });
};
```

And in the Controller:

```
$scope.updateSomething = function () {
  $http.post('/somethingupdate/:id', {
    field1: $scope.somethingField1,
    field2: $scope.somethingField2,
    field3: $scope.somethingField3,

  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.somethings.push({
    field1: $scope.somethingField1,
    field2: $scope.somethingField2,
    field3: $scope.somethingField3,
    });
    $scope.somethingField1 = '';
    $scope.somethingField2 = '';
    $scope.somethingField3 = '';
  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Ops: " + data);
  });
};
```

Here is the result in console:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "field", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM  "Soemthings" AS "Something" WHERE "Something"."id" = 'id value';
Executing (default): UPDATE "Somethings" SET "field1"='' "field2" = '' "field3" = '' "updatedAt"='2016-06-09 20:20:57.384 +00:00' WHERE "id" = id value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED!**

You are passing an empty set when submit, check your ***updateform*** variable

You need to add ng-models to your inputs that starts with ***updateform***

```
 <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.field1" type="number" name="field1" ng-init="updateform.field3 =something.field3">
```

And so on. Since you said you are using `$scope.somethingField` lets use it in your markup, then i added a hidden field for `id` as well.

```
<div class="container">
 <div ng-controller="SomethingCtrl">
<form ng-submit="updateSomething(updateform)" role="form">
  <div class="datagrid"><table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> ID </th>
      <th> field1 </th>
      <th> field2 </th>
      <th> field3 </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="something in somethings | filter:{id:1} | orderBy:'id' | limitTo: 1 track by $index">
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="updateform.id" ng-init="updateform.id = something.id">
        {{something.id}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.field1" type="text" ng-init="updateform.field1 = something.field1" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.field2" type="text" ng-init="updateform.field2 = something.field2" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.field3" type="text" ng-init="updateform.field3 =something.field3" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit"><strong>Update</strong></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Then in your controller outside the function $scope.updateSomething:

```
$scope.updateform = {
    field1: '',
    field2: '',
    field3: ''
}
```

Then in you controller function for update add parameter field, try to check console logs if `field` contains data:

```
$scope.updateSomething = function (field) {
    console.log(field);
    $http.post('/somethingupdate/' + field.id, {
        field: field,
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.somethings.push({
           field: field
        });
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Ops: " + data);
    });
};
```

Here is a working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebautistajr/e7ky18uv/4/)

Comment: Hey, @Efx I have tried this but it did not help. When I update, only the updatedAt and one field attribute are updated. The field attribute has a value of '', which I believe comes from the `$scope.somethingField = '';` statement in the controller. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: On your function in the controller can you add a parameter field and use that instead in $scope.somethingfield

Comment: To replace `$scope.somethingField = '';` ?

Comment: But, also when using ng-model when the form is submitted nothing is submitted as a parameter

Comment: On that update can you send me the result of the console.log?

Comment: Yes, it might be an hour or so, but I will.

Comment: I believe we have a misunderstanding. Field# is an attribute of the something table. So for example, say something is Client. Client has three attributes, Field1 = Name, Field2 = Age, Field3 = Height. I was trying to generalize my post such to not cloud the meaning by being too specific. So, I think we are thinking of $scope.somethingField a little differently, yes ?

Comment: I understand what you presented, its just that we dont have any sample plunker solution to play with, so this is like test answer, please do not accept it as answer then until i helped you solved your problem, so what was the result of your console.log JSON values? if it stays blank it only means that your controller function is not getting any value from your form, upon submit you can check your post to `/somethingupdate/:id` check for the Request Body if it did send the data, i believe as you can see in my solution you need to add $.param() or you can remove it, ill try to make a fiddle ex.

Comment: can you provide me the object value for somethings?

Comment: What do you mean by object value

Comment: `somethings` your value for this

Comment: Well, I have client table with attributes Name, Age, and Height. Say one record here is John, 27, 6 ft

Comment: Here is a sample of a simulation of your problem, i have mistakes in my presented answer above but will edit it if you understand this sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebautistajr/e7ky18uv/4/), F12 and go to console.log check the Object being passed, so do my suggestion in the jsfiddle at the bottom of the javascript in your backend recieving (is that nodejs).

Comment: Okay, it works for the most part. I have had to change it to this     `$scope.updateform = {
        Name: '',
       Age: '',
       Height: '',
        Haircolor:'',
    }
    $scope.updateSomething = function(updateform) {
         $http.post('/somethingupdate/'+something.id, {updateform});
    };` But, I am stuck on getting the id attribute and injecting into the url.

Comment: where did your `something.id` came from? you can pass it also to `function(updateform,id)`

Comment: Id is a parameter that resembles the primary key of the table

Comment: I am still having issues with the id. The id is from the data got in the first part of my module, such that the client has an id in the database.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of youre current code? Send it to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114777/discussion-between-tetraphenom-and-efx).

Comment: I will check after work, will send you the fix later.

Comment: Have you been able to looks at it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-model="something.field1" instead of value="{{something.field1}}" and so on..